# How to quickly load a small variable from huge .mat files?

Tags: matlab, centos

I have a `trained_model.mat` file, whose size is around 23 GB.

This file has 6 variables,

- 4 of them are `1 X 1` doubles
- 1 is an `48962 X 1` double
- 1 is a `TreeBagger` object (this occupies maximum size).

I want to quickly load, only the `48962 X 1` variable whose name is `Y_hat`, but it is taking like eternity. I am running this code on a compute node on an cluster with 256GB of RAM, and no other user processes are running on this system.

I have already tried using `load('trained_model.mat', 'Y_hat');`, but this also takes very long time. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the future, it may be better to just save them separately

Comment: It might be the case the file i/o is your bottleneck, since the compute node needs access to the file system in order to read the mat file. You can verify if this is the case by running the same line of code on the master node. How long does it take there?  Also, can you `ssh` from a compute node to the master node?

Comment: Have you tried [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html)?

Comment: Just out of interest, what does "very long" mean?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yeah, I realized that, and I have started to save big files separately. But, I have to spend a lot of time reading already saved results.

Comment: Indeed, the big problem of supercomputers is that memory access is slow!

Answer (score 0):

```
% Create a MAT-file object, m, connected to the MAT-file

% The object allows you to access and change variables directly in a MAT-file

% without having to load the variables into memory

m = matfile('trained_model.mat');

your_data_48962x1 = m.Y_hat;

% It should be faster than load
```

[more info on mathworks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html)